# React components for highlighting text and reloading highlights from files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highlight, react-component

I am working on creating a text highlighter with these functionalities:

- It allows the users to select and highlight/unhighlight the text on
  the page with different colors.
- Load the highlights from a file (search for the words from the file in the page and highlight them).

I was able to create the highlight and delete highlight function using rangy https://github.com/timdown/rangy (which is not a react component), but whenever any component on the page sets the state using (setState method) those highlights disappear.

Also, previously highlighted items are not easily loaded into the page using this method.

That is why I am redeveloping this functionality again, and I want to know what would be the right approach to tackle this issue?

I have been thinking of developing a custom React component for highlighting and adding it to the page, but for this approach, I want to know how to dynamically add the highlights component when the user selects a text on the page without losing it when the state is updated.

A link to a useful resource on how to add dynamic components would be convenient for me as I have been searching for the correct way to tackle this issue for a while and I think I might not be heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React will re-render anything where the state has changed.  This will cause your highlighting to disappear as the elements are not the same even if they appear the same.

React will *also* intelligently **not** re-render if you set [a unique key](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) property in many cases.  This lets React know to reuse the component.

If the state is correctly changing, and you only want to sometimes prevent a re-render, you should implement a [shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to control the re-render conditions yourself.

Comment: What if the highlights weren't a react component? and If I change them to react components I don't know where their location would be on the page.  Is there a way to add these components without prespecifying their location?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  However, you can always select items using ids or class names in plain old javascript.